# Using Uppy to upload Files from ReactJs to PHP server( Yii2)

Tags: php, reactjs, file-upload, yii2

I have a Form in `ReactJs` and I want to submit both data and files to my php  API ( Yii2) endpoint. (I do not want to use the raw Input file upload form as I want to have functions like file preview, cropping and most importantly progress bar on file upload)

After doing some research, I came across Uppy which seems to be a great tool to help in this task. I have been going through the docs and other materials for a few days now.

I have written a function to upload files using uppy file uploader following tutorials such as h`ttps://uppy.io/docs/react/`. My function is very buggy as

1. I  do not even see thumbnails generated from files uploaded, I do not see any information on my DragDrop Component.
2. I am not able to upload the files to my Yii2 API endpoint. I get the error Reason:

> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing with results such
>   as: Object { successful: [], failed: (1) […], uploadID:
>   "cjs3mua0g0001245zctq3nbqa" }

Here is my code for the uppy function

```
AvatarPicker(currentAvatar ){
  const {user} = this.props
  const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({
             username: user.username
        })
    };

  const uppy = Uppy({ autoProceed: true })
      .use(Dashboard, { trigger: '#select-files' })
      .use(GoogleDrive, { target: Dashboard, serverUrl: apiConstants.API_GENERAL_URL+'changeprofilepic' })
      .use(Instagram, { target: Dashboard, serverUrl: apiConstants.API_GENERAL_URL+'changeprofilepic' })
      .use(Webcam, { target: Dashboard })
      .use(Tus, { endpoint:  apiConstants.API_GENERAL_URL+'changeprofilepic?access-token='+user.username, requestOptions })
      .on('complete', (result) => {
        console.log('Upload result:', result)
      })

return (
  <div>
    <img src={currentAvatar} alt="Current Avatar" />
    <DragDrop
      uppy={uppy}
      locale={{
        strings: {
          // Text to show on the droppable area.
          // `%{browse}` is replaced with a link that opens the system file selection dialog.
          dropHereOr: 'Drop here or %{browse}',
          // Used as the label for the link that opens the system file selection dialog.
          browse: 'browse'
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
)
```

And in my component render function, I call the AvatarPicker class as show

```
{
   this.AvatarPicker('./../images/master.png')
}
```

Any heads up on this issue, propose solutions, fixes or new Ideas to get around my task is highly appreciated.

Comment: you need to configure the behaviors on you Yii2 API to allow the domains from where you are sending the request add the relative code from the API.

Comment: Muhammd thanks, unfortunately I don't even see the uppy dashboard. If I upload  my images using Uppy,, I do not even see the dashboard talk less of editing them